# How come "self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;" makes app crash on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I would like to point out that self is a WelcomeViewController and that it inherits from UIViewController :

*WelcomeViewController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WelcomeViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSUserDefaults* preferences;


@end
```

*WelcomeViewController.m*

```
#import "WelcomeViewController.h"
#import "GESceneController.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface WelcomeViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *highScoreLabel;

@end

@implementation WelcomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
    [self.scoreLabel setText:self.score];

    NSString* highScoreText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Meilleur score : %ld",
                               [self.preferences integerForKey:@"highscore"]];

    [self.highScoreLabel setText:highScoreText];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

and I get the error : [WelcomeViewController setCanDisplayBannerAds:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d97f080

Comment: Are you asking how to solve this? Or pointing out a bug? or what? Read SO FAQ cause I don't think this question follows it at this current time.

Comment: you're right, I've edited the topic and added a question mark. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Have you imported the iAd file into your linked frameworks and libraries? If not, goto your build info and scroll all the way to the bottom, there you will find 'linked frameworks..' and add the framework into you app.

Comment: I felt stupid. lol. Forgot I was testing admob and not really iAd so haven't linked it. hahaha